# Why does my Ajax response display over my navigation bar?

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax, navbar

Whenever I'm scrolling my mouse, all the listed admin cards come over the navbar. This is a very irritating flaw and I can't seem to understand where I went wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```css
#mainsec {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#navv {
  background-color: #333; /* Black background color */
  position: fixed; /* Make it stick/fixed */
  top: 0; /* Stay on top */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  transition: top 0.3s; /* Transition effect when sliding down (and up) */
}

#navv a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.568);
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/admin_dash.css">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navv">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="../../assets/logo.png" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top"> Phemesoft
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#sec1">Admins</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#sec2">Manage Admins</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#sec3">Course Content</a>
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column">
      <div id="sec1">
        <div class="row" id="mainsec">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2>Admins</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-5 cards-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="sec2">
        <div class="row" id="mainsec">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>User to Admin</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <form class="form" action="makeadmin" method="POST">
              Enter email:
              <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Check</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="sec3">
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="mainsec">
          <h1>Add course content</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $.ajax({
      url: "listadmins",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(response) {
        var $results = $(".cards-wrapper");
        for (var a = 0; a < response.length; a++) {
          // console.log(response[a].Name);
          $results.append(
            '<div class="card"><div class="card-body"><h6 class="card-title">' +
            response[a].Name +
            '</h6></div></div>'
          );
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
      var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navv").style.top = "0";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("navv").style.top = "-50px";
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    };
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's an image of the issue:
[The card appears over then nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pssk1.png)

Ps: *I haven't posted the mapping of /listadmins because it;s just normal Database query*

Comment: The fact that it's an ajax response isn't relevant to your problem. (this is just an html/css issue)

Comment: use higher z-index in your nav.

Comment: @disinfor  some things are not closed/extra but that is not true of the div or nav you state

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yep! I completely missed an opening element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all of guys for responding. I found the answer in one the comments. It was to use a higher z-index value for the navbar.

```
#navv {
  background-color: #333; /* Black background color */
  position: fixed; /* Make it stick/fixed */
  top: 0; /* Stay on top */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  transition: top 0.3s; /* Transition effect when sliding down (and up) */
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: this probably means your document does not flow properly IMHO

Answer (score 0):

remove *'position: relative'* from the card class

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the ajax directly but more the rest of the page.

Your html is invalid

- head tag not closed
- body tag not opened
- duplicate id `mainsec` - not using them really so I made them a class and removed the id's
- some other invalid markup

Hard to see the issue here so I adjusted the size slightly for this site

Now that we got that strait, you can adjust the margins and padding on the tops with `mt-5 pt-4` however you wish, toy around with this and see where you get things to move.

```css
.mainsec {
  height: 5em;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#navv {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navv a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.568);
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/admin_dash.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navv">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="../../assets/logo.png" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top" alt="Phemesoft logo">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#sec1">Admins</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#sec2">Manage Admins</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#sec3">Course Content</a>
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container mt-6">
    <div class="">
      <div id="sec1">
        <div class="mainsec mt-5">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h2>Admins</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-7 mt-5 pt-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-8 cards-wrapper">
                <div class="cards-wrapper">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h6 class="card-title">Pretend append
                      </h6>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h6 class="card-title">Pretend append
                      </h6>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="sec2">
        <div class="row mainsec">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>User to Admin</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <form class="form" action="makeadmin" method="POST">
              Enter email:
              <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Check</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row"  id="sec3">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mainsec">
          <h1>Add course content</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $.ajax({
      url: "listadmins",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(response) {
        var $results = $(".cards-wrapper");
        for (var a = 0; a < response.length; a++) {
          $results.append(
            '<div class="card"><div class="card-body"><h6 class="card-title">' +
            response[a].Name +
            '</h6></div></div>'
          );
        }
      }
    });

    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
      var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navv").style.top = "0";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("navv").style.top = "-50px";
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey, yeah I completely forgot the tags, but I'm using mainsec, to divide it into sections. Like when you click on the navbar it'll scroll down to a new page, And mainsec is providing the height and width to fit one content on the screen.